# Surjectivity of $\frac{z}{(1-z)^2}$ onto $\mathbb C$ from the open unit disc

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Can you say something about the surjectivity of $\frac{z}{(1-z)^2}$ onto $\mathbb C$ from the open unit disc?

My attempt:  I am getting $\frac{z}{(1-z)^2}=w \neq 0 \Rightarrow z=\frac{2+\frac{1}{w}\pm \sqrt{\frac{4}{w}+\frac{1}{w^2}}}{2}$, but iam not sure $z$ in open unit disc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$f(z) = \frac{z}{(1-z)^2}$ is the so-called [Koebe function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koebe_quarter_theorem#Koebe_function). It maps the unit disk conformally to the “slit domain” $\Bbb C \setminus (-\infty, -1/4]$, which can be seen by writing the function in the form
$$
 f(z) = \frac 14 \left( \frac{1+z}{1-z}\right)^2 - \frac 14 \, .
$$

Answer (score 3):

It is not onto. Let us first check that this map is injective: $\frac a {(1-a)^{2}}=\frac b {(1-b)^{2}}$ implies that $a+ab^{2}-2ab=b+ba^{2}-2ab$ or $(a-b) (1-ab)=0$. $1-ab \neq 0$ because $|ab| <1$. Hence $a=b$. If this map is onto then  $\mathbb C$ would be conformally equivalent to the unit disk which is false.

[The inverse of this map would be a bounded analytic function, hence a  constant].