# Given $f(z)$ defined on the open disk $ \{ z \in \mathbb{C}\mid |z| <1 \}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Given $f(z)= \sum_{n \ge 0} n z^n$ defined on  the open disk $ \{ z\in \mathbb{C} \mid |z| <1 \}$.
Then choose the correct option

1. $f$ is onto
2. $f$ is one-to-one
3. $f$ attains every complex value
4. $f$ is  one-to-one  but not onto

**My attempt**:  By open mapping theorem it will be onto and injective  and also $f$ attains  every  complex value   because  every real is  complex. So option 1,2,3 are correct.

Is it correct?

Comment: The open map theorem does not imply surjectivity nor injectivity.

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3465386/surjectivity-of-fracz1-z2-onto-mathbb-c-from-the-open-unit-disc